# Could someone please explain Declarative Database Schema

Tags: magento2, database, magento2.3

So, I read that Magento 2.3 will be introducing **Declarative Database Schema**.

> Today, when you want to alter the schema of a Magento database, the
>   pattern used to accomplish this is to use the InstallSchema and
>   UpgradeSchema classes where code is written to alter the schema.
>   Magento 2.3 will change the recommended way by implementing a
>   declarative database schema.

Please, could someone help explain **what this means** and **why it's so beneficial**. And is this referring to changes to the DB itself or just the scripts used to install and upgrade.

Thanks.

Comment: if u need still https://github.com/bdcrops/BDC_Declarative

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to attempt to answer my own question here based on a post I just read [here](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-DevBlog/A-Declarative-Approach-for-Database-Schema-Upgrades/ba-p/70763).

From what I understand... Right now, when a module is developed for Magento 2 it has to be written in a way that can easily invite bugs and complexity.

**Common issues include:**

- Having different types of scripts makes the system unstable and difficult
- Excessive complexity of installation
- There is no update validation

The upcoming update will allow developers to restructure parts of their modules so that it can be written much clearer.

**Potential solutions include**

- Avoids missed or repeated SQL operations
- Performance improvements
- Ability to revert to a previous version

This will result in a reduction of potential bugs, easier development and performance improvements.